# How to sending payload in TCP UDP

Tags: tcp, udp, payload

I have to test the performance of Ethernet and WI-FI by using Iperf as both in TCP and UDP, I have to send payload 100, 200, 300 bytes respectively from client to server but I don't know how to sending payload

ps1. how can I see the data rate during sending data?
ps2. [at first I misunderstanding window size and payload are the same, so I set -w 100](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1T02.png)

Answer (score 0):

You call `send()` (TCP), or `sendto()` or `sendmsg()` (UDP).